# Typescript crashes on ES11 syntax

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-next, ts-node

What is the reason typescript is throwing error when I try to use ES11 nullish coalescing operator?

Exapmle:

```
const a = undefined;
const b = a ?? 'test';
```

is resulting in:

```
dev_project-shared_server | Using ts-node version 8.10.2, typescript version 3.9.5
dev_project-shared_server | /usr/src/app/services/server/src/index.ts:21
dev_project-shared_server |     const b = a ?? 'test';
dev_project-shared_server |                  ^
dev_project-shared_server | 
dev_project-shared_server | SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
dev_project-shared_server |     at Object.compileFunction (vm.js:344:18)
dev_project-shared_server |     at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1048:15)
dev_project-shared_server |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1082:27)
dev_project-shared_server |     at Module._compile (/usr/src/app/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:547:25)
dev_project-shared_server |     at Module.m._compile (/tmp/ts-node-dev-hook-7547668788214215.js:57:25)
dev_project-shared_server |     at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:10)
dev_project-shared_server |     at require.extensions.<computed> (/tmp/ts-node-dev-hook-7547668788214215.js:59:14)
dev_project-shared_server |     at Object.nodeDevHook [as .ts] (/usr/src/app/node_modules/ts-node-dev/lib/hook.js:61:7)
dev_project-shared_server |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:32)
dev_project-shared_server |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:875:14)
dev_project-shared_server | [ERROR] 06:58:29 SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
```

my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"],
  "include": ["**/*.ts"]
}
```

---

Comment: Support for that operator was added in TS 3.7: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#nullish-coalescing. Your ts-node and typescript seem up-to-date, I couldn't replicate that behaviour locally.

Answer (score -2):

What is the version of your node?
The nullish coalescing operator (??) is supported on nodejs v14:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference